# Get and store auth_token in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, session, authentication, google-chrome-extension, storage

I am implementing a chrome extension. Where an user log in(email and password) and get auth token from 3rd party. I want to store this auth token so when sending another request to same party I can use this token. What is good approach to do this. Should I store it ? If yes how? Else what should I do?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity

Answer (score 14):

You can save it in Storage.

Step 1: You need to add the `storage` permission in `manifest.json`

> "permissions": [
> "storage"
> ],

Step 2: Set the token in storage

```
chrome.storage.local.set({ "authToken": <YOUR_TOKEN_HERE> }, function(){
    //  Data's been saved boys and girls, go on home
});
```

Step 3: Get the token from storage

```
var authToken='';
chrome.storage.local.get(["authToken"], function(items){
    debugger;
    // NOTE: check syntax here, about accessing 'authToken'
    authToken= items.authToken
});
```

Comment: Is it safe to store token in storage ? Can I use sessionStorage ?

Comment: safety point of view no one method is safe at front end but in sessionStorage any user can see the token easily using dev tool so i am suggesstion to tyou is use  chrome.storage.local.get().

Comment: @PankajRupapara Yes, they can see the token using the dev tool, but they are only seeing their own token. The problem with sessionStorage arises when a hacker can access it via cross-site-scripting (XSS).

Comment: It says here https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage that "Confidential user information should not be stored! The storage area isn't encrypted." So is it safe to store tokens? I'm not sure. Seems okay but it could mean that anyone that has access to your PC might be able to access the token

Comment: Your JWT itself is encrypted, no? So even if someone has access to it, what could they do with it? Reverse-engineer it? They do not know the seed(s) you used to generate the JWT (on your server). In theory your server should be checking JWT legitimacy along with other signals to make sure someone is authorized. Regarding "confidential user information", I think that is in reference to personal data as plain text ie username, email, ip, etc. which obviously IS super exposed when kept in cookies or localStorage.

Comment: Using localStorage to store JWT seems to be fine as long as you take security steps. See this article: https://pragmaticwebsecurity.com/articles/oauthoidc/localstorage-xss.html